# Create different GUI components as a separate class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So, I have a top level JPanel(this is added to JFrame) which contains all the other components. Now I have all the other components, mostly JPanels, which in turn contains buttons, textfields and all the other basic components. So, at the lowest level, I created a class which extends JPanel and I added all the components there. So, my question is, "is it good practice to build a GUI this way?".

Comment: *"I created a class which extends JPanel .. "is it a good practice to build a GUI this way"* Don't extend GUI components unless necessary  (changing methods with `@Override`). The only time (I can think of) that it makes sense to extend a panel is for custom painting. I've never seen a good reason to extend a frame.

Comment: I would keep your application logic separate from your view logic. Have classes dedicated to what the view 'looks like' and what it 'does'. But, yes, container view components should handle their child components. And only allow access to these child components view an interface, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds good. If it's a big project (with lots of classes) I would even go further and put it in another directory. It's usually good practice to separate the logic from the other components of the code.